# Зацикленная функция на hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать без setInterval выполнение функции пока курсор hover элемента? Что бы функция была зациклена.

```js
$("#left").hover(function() {
  left_statuses();
})

function left_statuses() {
  var scroll = $(".scroll").scrollLeft();
  var new_scroll = scroll + 100;
  $(".scroll").scrollLeft(new_scroll);
}
```

```css
.left {
  z-index: 1;
}

.scroll {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scroll div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
  LEFT
</div>

<div class="scroll">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторные смещения происходят безо всяких `setInterval`:

```js
var scroll = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll")[0];
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var step = 20;

left.onmouseover = function() {
    scroll.scrollLeft += step;
    left.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
left.onmouseout = function() {
    scroll.scrollLeft += step;
    left.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}
```

```css
.left {
  z-index: 1;
}

.scroll {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scroll div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  LEFT
</div>

<div class="scroll">
  <div></div>
</div>
```